How to find area of circle using double integral?
I was trying to verify Stokes' theorem for a function and this is where I'm confused.
$$\nabla \times \mathbf{v} = \mathbf{ k} \equiv\text{ct. vector}$$
So,
$$\displaystyle\oint (\nabla \times\mathbf{v})\cdot\mathrm d\mathbf A = k \iint \mathrm dx\, \mathrm dy$$
and we have,
$$x^2 + y^2 = r^2$$
I know we can directly take integral $\mathrm d\mathbf A$ as area of circle because we know it's a circle. But I wanna do it with proper calculation solving this double integral. My main doubt is how to approach it? I tried it this way
$$2\int_{r}^{-r}\int_{r}^{-r} dydx$$
But this ends up being zero.
It only works if we ignore first integral limits and only apply limits during the second integral.
$$ 2\int_{r}^{-r} \int dydx = 2\int_{r}^{-r} ydx = \pi r^2 $$
But why do we ignore the limits for y? Normally for surface integrals, don't we apply limits to both integrals?

For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., here, here, here and here.

Use polar coordinates, of course.

@TedShifrin How can I do it without polar coordinates? I have elaborated my question, please check it out.

If you really want to do it in rectangular coordinates, first notice $-\sqrt{1-x^2} \leq y \leq \sqrt{1-x^2}$. But that's just the hardest of several ways.

Hi, welcome to Math SE. Hint: see these sections of the same article.

All the hints required - I think, they are already all in the comments. The only thing I'd suggest is using trigonometric substitution. Below is the proof of the formula of the area of a circle using integrals.
The equation of a circle of radius $r>0$ centered at the origin is $x^2 + y^2 = r^2$. We now can isolate y and obtain the equation of the upper-half circle: $ y= \sqrt{r^2-x^2}$. Hence: $\frac{1}{2}A=\int_{-r}^r\sqrt{r^2-x^2} \ \text{d}x = 2\int_0^r \sqrt{r^2 - x^2} \ \text{d}x $
The integral above can be solved using trigonometric substitution. Substitute $x=r\sin \theta$. Then the integral is changed into another one:
$$
\frac{1}{4}A=\int_0^r
\sqrt{r^2-x^2}\ \text{d}x \\
\frac{\text{d}x}{\text{d}\theta}=r\cos \theta, \sqrt{r^2-r^2 \sin^2 \theta}=r\cos\theta \Rightarrow \\ \Rightarrow\sqrt{r^2-x^2}\ \text{d}x=r^2 \cos^2\theta \ \text{d}\theta \\
r\sin\theta = 0 \Rightarrow \theta = 0, r\sin \theta=  r \Rightarrow \theta = \frac{\pi}{2}\\
I = \int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} \cos^2 \theta  \ \text{d}\theta = \int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} \cos^2 (\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta)  \ \text{d}\theta=\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\sin^2 \theta \ \text{d}\theta \\
\therefore 2I = \int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}(\sin^2\theta + \cos^2 \theta) \text{d}\theta= \int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} \text{d}\theta = \frac{\pi}{2} \Rightarrow \\
\Rightarrow I = \frac{\pi}{4}\Rightarrow\frac{1}{4}A=\frac{\pi r^2}{4} \\
\therefore A=\pi r^2$$ $\square$
The integral in the beggining comes from the double integral:
$$ \iint_\Omega \text{d}A=\int_{-r}^r\int_{-\sqrt{r^2-x^2}}^{\sqrt{r^2-x^2}}\text{d}y\text{d}x = 2\int_{-r}^r\sqrt{r^2-x^2} \ \text{d}x = \\= 4\int_0^r \sqrt{r^2 - x^2} \ \text{d}x$$
where $ \Omega = \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : x^2 + y^2 = r^2 \}$

Oh I see, I was taking the limits for y wrong and thus getting zero as I clarified in the edit. Can you tell me why don't we take the limits -r to r for y as well?

The limits for $y$ are taken, as it is here defined as the function $\sqrt{r^2 - x^2}$. which takes values between $0$ and $r$ for $x \in [-r,r]$. And for the other half of the circle, it is defined as the negative of this function, so the limits ultimately match, so $y$ still fits in the interval $[-r,r]$. This is visible in the double integral just below the proof.

If we took the limits $y \in [-r,r]$ and $x \in [-r,r]$ at once, we would also get a square of side length $2r$. Though taking limits for $y$ as $y \in [-r,r]$ would not be a mistake, unless we make a condition that $|x|=\sqrt{r^2-x^2}$, since this would also produce a circle $\Omega$ of radius $r$.
